# svn update or checkout problem : Can't read length line in file '/home/username/svn_repository/db/revs/0/697'

Tags: ubuntu, subversion

My latest revision is 703 after svn committed. But When I execute the svn update or svn checkout commands from Client machine it throws.

```
    svn: REPORT of '/home/username/svn_repository/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk size: connection was closed by server (http://10.192.1.5)
```

I checked the log messages from svn server side. It shows

```
    [Wed Sep 17 09:48:17 2014] [error] [client 10.192.1.175] Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
    [Wed Sep 17 09:48:17 2014] [error] [client 10.192.1.175] A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #200002]
    [Wed Sep 17 09:48:17 2014] [error] [client 10.192.1.175] Can't read length line in file '/home/username/svn_repository/db/revs/0/697'  [500, #200002].
```

I searched some links, they told to do svnadmin recover and verify commands. I tried svnadmin recover svn_repository, the output will be like this

```
    Repository lock acquired.
    Please wait; recovering the repository may take some time...

    Recovery completed.
    The latest repos revision is 703.
```

After I tried svnadmin verify command

```
    * Verified revision 693.
    * Verified revision 694.
    * Verified revision 695.
    * Verified revision 696.
    * Verified revision 697.
    * Verified revision 698.
    svnadmin: Can't read length line in file 'svn_repository/db/revs/0/697'
```

Both the svnserver and svn client using ubuntu 12.04 only.

How to solve this issue ?